# How to Skip Sites with No Access from Sp2013 Search Crawls

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-scope, crawl-rules

I have about 56 different Sites in our site collections that are set to No access. Every time Search Service Crawl hits those sites it prompts us with:

```
Access to this SharePoint site has been blocked. Please contact the administrator to resolve this problem. ( Error from SharePoint site: Access to this Web site has been blocked. Please contact the administrator to resolve this problem.;
```

Can we add the crawl rule in place that will skip those sites that are in No access mode. Any articles or the tutorials that would help me understand how to set one up would be very helpful.

Also please suggest if this is a good practice to skip those sites from crawl?

Thank You

Comment: can you move all the lock site collections into different web app? totally different approach

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. Under site settings you should have a Search and Offline Availability option where you can set it to not show in search.
2. You can add a query rule that removes results based on site URL's.  If they are unique URL's you will either need seperate rules for all of them or make sure the Query is configured to retrieve the correct URL's. You will use something like this:

   -Path:{Site.http://}
3. You can also use a custom result source, and set that up to only return data from the sites you do want included. If you do this you'll need to setup search page to use your result source.

Comment: Thank You for the response Jesus, Can you elaborate little more about your third option. I personally dont want to add each one of them in the in crawl rule, i am looking more of a automated approach that utilizes the Lock Status of the Sites in the Site collection to target all sites in future. If there is some powershell solution you can suggest that will be beneficial too.

Answer (score 1):

As Jesus told..The best way to skip the crawling is to create crawl rules for the diffirent sites. Following is the PowerShell Command using which you can incorporate crawl rules.

```
$Path = "http://SharePointSite/sites/test/*"
$SearchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
if ((Get-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlRule -SearchApplication $SearchApp -Identity $Path -EA SilentlyContinue)) 
{
    # remove crawl rule; "-confirm:$false" disables confirmation dialog which would otherwise pop up
   Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlRule -SearchApplication $SearchApp -Identity $Path -confirm:$false
}
$Rule = New-SPEnterpriseSearchCrawlRule -SearchApplication $SearchApp -Path $Path -Type ExclusionRule -CrawlAsHttp 0 -FollowComplexUrls 0
$Rule.Update()
```